# Laravel query with if condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I wanted to insert data into table if the condition is met. Is there such things as this codes below?

```
DB::table('food')->insert([
    'dessert' => $dessert1,
    if(beverage == 1)
        'drinks' => 1;
    else if(beverage == 2)
        'drinks' => 2;
]);
...
```

Comment: Check this condition above insert query and use that variable

Comment: You have to write code withing if..else..if not like you wrote i.e. if..else..if  not  acceptable under query. Let me if you required more explanation.

Comment: what is beverage where do you get it ? if it is a variable you can just do `drinks=$beverage`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: (Food is your model)

```
$food = new Food(); // new instance of food model
$food->dessert = $dessert1;
if(beverage == 1)
 $food->drinks = 1;
else if(beverage == 2)
 $food->drinks = 2;
$food->save();
```

That's how you handle if conditions with query, but according to your question you can do the following:

```
DB::table('food')->insert([
    'dessert' => $dessert1,
    'drinks' => $beverage,
]);
```

Comment: This is best way.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this way:

**Code:**

```
$drinks = 0;
if(beverage == 1)
   $drinks = 1;
else if(beverage == 2)
   $drinks = 2;

DB::table('food')->insert([
    'dessert' => $dessert1,
    'drinks'  => $drinks
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to make an array of predefined values as `beverage => drink`

```
$drinks = [ 1 => 1, 2 => 2 ];

DB::table('food')->insert([
    'dessert' => $dessert1,
    'drinks' => $drinks[$beverage];
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
if($beverage == 1){
  DB::table('food')->insert([
    'dessert' => $dessert1,
    'drinks' => 1,

]);

}

if(beverage == 2){
  DB::table('food')->insert([
    'dessert' => $dessert1,
    'drinks' => 2,

]);

}
```

**OR**

```
$food = new Food;
$food->dessert = $dessert1;

if($beverage == 1){
  $food->drinks = 1;
}

if($beverage == 1){
  $food->drinks = 2;
}

$food->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to pre-determine the value with the if outside the insert:

```
$values = [ "dessert" => $dessert1 ];
if($beverage == 1) //How on earth did you ever expect if (beverage == 1) to work in anything?
     $values['drinks'] = 1;
else if($beverage == 2)
    $values['drinks'] = 2;

DB::table('food')->insert($values);
```

You can also determine the value inline using the [ternary operator (?:)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
DB::table('food')->insert([
    'dessert' => $dessert1,
    'drinks' => ($beverage==1?1:($beverage==2?2:null));
]);
```

In your case the following may also work:

```
DB::table('food')->insert([
    'dessert' => $dessert1,
    'drinks' => $beverage
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make condition in `DB` like this

```
$query = DB::table('food');

$query->insert(['dessert' => $dessert1]);

if(beverage == 1)
    $query->insert(['drinks' => 1]);
else if(beverage == 2)
    $query->insert(['drinks' => 2]);
```

Comment: i tried your way, it seems that only "desert" manage to stored in "food table" but not "drinks". "Drinks" return null in "food table".

Answer (score 0):

Do your condition checking first, that will make your code clear and readable
like `@RJParikh`

```
$drinks = 0;
if(beverage == 1)
   $drinks = 1;
else if(beverage == 2)
   $drinks = 2;
```

Or if you have limited number of entry do like `@Zayn Ali`

```
$drinks = [ 1 => 1, 2 => 2 ]; // $beverageValue => $drinksValue
```

Then use insert -

```
DB::table('food')->insert([
    ......,
    ......,
]);
```

But keep in mind if you use insert like this you have to make the fields fillable from model. Better you make a model on food table and follow `@Firas Rassas` answer. Combining answers your code will look like below -

```
 $drinks = 0;
    if(beverage == 1)
       $drinks = 1;
    else if(beverage == 2)
       $drinks = 2;

    $food = new Food(); // new instance of food model
    $food->dessert = $dessert1;
    $food->drinks = $drinks;
    $food->save();
```